# Download apk failed when resume download with httpUrlConnection

Tags: android, download

I meet a problem when download apk with HttpUrlConnection.

I develop a app about 30Mb, and I create a manager to check the latest version and download it.
Because of its size, I checked the downloaded file size and resume downloading if connection was cutted off or app was shutdown by system.

The problem is that a parse error happened when install downloading apk if the whole downloading process was interrupted once.
This is the error message:

Parse error: There was a problem parsing the package.

And here is my code of downloading:

```
private File downloadApk(File aApkFile, String aUrl, long aStartPosition, long aEndPosition) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(aUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(5 * 1000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Range", StringFormatter.format("bytes=%s-", aStartPosition));
        conn.connect();
        sendUpdateNotification(0, 100); // update notifaction info
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(aApkFile);

        int currentPercent = 0;
        long currentDownloadSize = aStartPosition;
        byte readBuffer[] = new byte[1024 * 10];
        int byteReadSize = 0;
        while (!((byteReadSize = inputStream.read(readBuffer)) <= 0)) {
            fileOutputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, byteReadSize);
            currentDownloadSize += byteReadSize;
            int index = (int) (currentDownloadSize * 100 / aEndPosition);
            if (index != currentPercent) {
                currentPercent = index;
                sendUpdateNotification(currentPercent, 100);
            }
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        return aApkFile;
    } catch (MalformedURLException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Version", aE.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Version", aE.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

ApkFile is the downloaded file which will not be null here.
StartPosition is the apkfile's size, and get by apkFile.length().
Endposition is the whole size of apk and get by conn.getContentLength().

Is there any ideas to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(aApkFile);` You create a new file there. So you would throw away a former partial download. You did not mention that the apk which was not parcelable had less bytes than the original one. Please inform us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting a former partial file with:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(aApkFile);
```

Change to appending mode:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(aApkFile, true);
```

Check file size of original and downloaded file. Every byte counts!

Comment: Also, I found that Connection.getResponseCode() should be checked.
In my test, when I turn off wifi and turn on it after a while, the response code are mostly 206. And if continue download with that response code, the apk file are mostly broken.
So I added 
` if (mConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                                continue;
                            }`
to make sure the connection is stable.

Comment: Indeed. Basic stuff.